# How does gear with limited amount of uses work?

Tags: objects, candela-obscura

I am not certain about how to interpret the rules about limited amount of item uses. It seems that either I can use the gear a certain number of times during each assignment, or I am only allowed to bring the item on *X* distinct assignments.

Page 52 states:

> **# of uses:** You may only use the item a number of times before it is gone. When you expend a gear slot to use it, reduce this number by 1.

If the first interpretation (**#** uses per assignment) is correct, then some of the example gear from page 190, such as the **Cassandra's Enchanting Perfume** and **Taylor House Coffee**, appears to have enough uses to last an entire assignment, making them quite powerful.

Conversely, if the second interpretation (**#** distinct assignments) is correct, which I assume is the intended ruling, the wording does seem a bit unclear. As the usage is reduced only when a gear slot is expended, it raises the question of whether gear not entirely consumed can be passed to other players without counting as a use.

In the scenario where one player, having already used a gear slot for **Cassandra's Enchanting Perfume** (p. 190), passes it to another player for use, it's unclear if this should count as an additional use when the second player did not expend a gear slot. Either

1. the game expects each player to use a gear slot to use the Perfume, which wouldn't work with how **Circle Gear** works
2. the second player also reduces the *# of uses* number by 1, which is not how the rule is written but I think the most intuitive ruling
3. once chosen you can use the gear as often as you want on the assignment, which would make it even more powerful that the first interpretation above.

Comment: I didnt find a [tag:candela-obscura] tag so I guess I created it? Please fix if this is wrong.

Comment: Yep, new game needs a new tag. I can add a tag description for it later today.